# Cannot Get Strings Across in a Socket Program

Tags: python, sockets

I have been looking at some code for a small chat program that I found online. It was originally written for 2.7, but it seems to work with 3.2. The only problem is that I cannot send strings, only numbers:

The chat.py file source code:

```
from socket import *
HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1) 
conn, addr = s.accept() 
print ('Connected by ' + str(addr)) 
i = True
while i is True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print ("Received " + repr(data))
    reply = str(input("Reply: "))
    conn.send(reply)
conn.close()
```

And the client.py source file:

```
from socket import * 
HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT)) # client-side, connects to a host
while True:
    message = str(input("Your Message: "))
    s.send(message)
    print ("Awaiting reply...")
    reply = s.recv(1024) # 1024 is max data that can be received
    print ("Received " + repr(reply))
s.close()
```

When I run these using two separate terminals, they work, but do not send strings.

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get or what happens when you send strings?

Answer (score 2):

When you work with sockets, the message you're passing around should probably be in bytes, `b'bytes'`. In Python 2.x, a [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) is actually what a [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) is in Python 3.x

So your message should be something like:

```
message = b'Message I want to pass'
```

Check here http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html for more information.

According to http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input `input` returns a `str`, which means you'll have to encode `message` into `bytes` as such:

```
message = message.encode()
```

Do verify that this is the right approach to convert `str` to `bytes` by checking the type of `message`.

Comment: Hi @woozyking, thank you for your reply. Would I format my message line like this: message = input(b"Your Message: ")

Comment: @user3089646 No, it just means that the input you're reading in has to be ensured as `bytes` type before passing it across sockets. So `message = input('Your message: ')` is perfectly fine, but after that and before `s.send(message)`, you have to make sure `type(message)` is `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket code is correct, it was just failing due to an unrelated error due to [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) vs `input`. You probably intended to read a string from the shell instead of reading a string and trying to evaluate it as Python code which is what `input` does.

Try this instead:

**chat.py**

```
from socket import *
HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1) 
conn, addr = s.accept() 
print ('Connected by ' + str(addr)) 
i = True
while i is True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print ("Received " + repr(data))
    reply = str(raw_input("Reply: "))
    conn.send(reply)
conn.close()
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import * 
HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT)) # client-side, connects to a host
while True:
    message = str(raw_input("Your Message: "))
    s.send(message)
    print ("Awaiting reply...")
    reply = s.recv(1024) # 1024 is max data that can be received
    print ("Received " + repr(reply))
s.close()
```

Comment: Hi @Stephen Diehl, thank you for your reply. I was happy to see this work, but realized that my IDLE was 3.2, but my shell was 2.7. When I updated it to 3.2, I get some more errors.

Comment: In Python 3, `raw_input` is deprecated. Instead `input` of Python 3 behaves like `raw_input` in Python 2